# Animate auto-layout constraint constant X to the center of the parent view

Tags: ios, animation, constants, center, nslayoutconstraint

I'll make it short and detailed for you.
What i succeed so far doing :

**1) I created an outlet for the desired constraints(Center X Alignment). I dont know if it matters , but i changed the multiplier for my needs(3:1)**

[image]

**2)Animate his constant**

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in

   self.btn_option_layout.constant = self.nan_view.center.x //Get center x value
   self.nan_view.layoutIfNeeded() // Parent View

            })
```

***Problem:***

Source position of the object :

[image]

Instead of animating the view to the center X like this :

[image]

It animates him for some reason to the left, this is the outcome :

[image]

I hope i was clear enough guys. Thank you for your time.

**What is the right way to calculate the constraints constant in order to center it on the X?**

Comment: At least for me it is not clear what is happening opposed to what you would expect to happen. Normally i would guess setting the constraint constant to 0 would align the centers!

Comment: it is already 0 @luk2302 , i added image , check it out

Comment: i know, that is why i do not understand what you are actually trying to achieve and what is happening instead. try to include screenshots of the entire device screen, that way the geometries are clear and it is visible better visible that something is not behaving correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
Despite @matt great answer(and working). The main purpose of my question was handling the constraints constant in order to center it on the X.
By the formula that might showed me :

```
**a1 = m*a2 + c**
```

I dived in. I understood several points :
Eventually i need that the second attribute(a2 - `button.center.x`) will in the same position of the first attribute(a1 - `self.view.center.x`).
so `a1 = a2 = self.view.center.x`
My multiplier equals 3(m - multiplier). And the C.. well we are looking for it :) so lets put this on :

```
a1 = m*a2 + c
c = a1 - m* a2
c = self.view.center.x - 3 * self.view.center.x
c = -2 * self.view.center.x
```

Code :

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.btn_option_layout.constant = -2 * self.nan_view.center.x
                self.nan_view.layoutIfNeeded()

            })
```

And to reverse it back to original spot :

Code :

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void 
 self.btn_option_layout.constant = 0     
 self.nan_view.layoutIfNeeded()

            })
```

Hope thats help. and matt thanks for the directions!

Comment: thanks, this was very helpful! didn't realize you could change the constant value for a centerX constraint.

Comment: @Crashalot Thanks, glad i could assist you!

Answer (score 4):

What are you are trying to do is exactly right. You have a constraint pinning the center of one view to the center of another view. If the multiplier to that constraint were 1, the view would sit in the center of the other view.

But your multiplier is not 1. And, as you have rightly observed, you cannot *change* the multiplier of an existing constraint — it is read-only.

But, no problem. Simply *replace the entire constraint* with a *different* constraint, identical to the first one except that its multiplier *is* 1. Now animate layout! It is a little-known fact that you can animate this sort of change in constraints.

Here is actual code:

```
let con2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.con.firstItem, attribute: self.con.firstAttribute, relatedBy: self.con.relation, toItem: self.con.secondItem, attribute: self.con.secondAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints([self.con])
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([con2])
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {self.view.layoutIfNeeded()})
```

And here is a looping gif that shows the resulting animation to the center:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir What you suggested is a great solution, but i still want to find the dynamic way of animate it via the constant. Any chance we could figure it out? :)

Comment: You "figure it out". If you wanted to animate it via the constant, you should have started with a constraint whose constant was non-zero, not a constraint whose multiplier was non-unary. But you started with the multiplier, and since you did, my answer tells you what to do in order to get the result you want. I provided sample code and a movie that proves it works. That's all I can do. Take it or leave it.

Comment: does the multiplier effects the constant when you change it?

Comment: I don't know what that means. You can _see_ the code. You know everything there is to know.

Comment: I mean that if i set multiplier who is different from 1,like i did above. And and im trying to change the constant , does the constant behave different when the multiplier is not 1?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78250/discussion-between-roi-mulia-and-matt).

Comment: @matt please don't get angry but what is con in your code? I tried doing var con = object.constraints but thats not it right...

Comment: @SaadRehman It is some NSLayoutConstraint that you want to change by replacement.

Comment: @matt is there a way to get it programmatically?

Comment: @SaadRehman I don't know what you mean by "get it". If you created it programmatically, just keep a reference to it. If you created it in a storyboard, make an outlet to it in the storyboard so you can refer to it in code, just like any other storyboard object. This has nothing to do with the question being discussed here! If you have a different question, please ask it as an actual question rather than extending the comments.